# How to find a particular bean in pom-imported dependencies?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-tool-suite

I am getting a wiring problem caused by one of beans imported from POM.xml.
What is **the proper way** of searching for a bean (@Service bean) in **Eclipse-STS**?

**What did not work:**

1. Looking in Spring Explorer did not work. Scanned the project to importing all config files but no luck.
2. Finding it as a resource (Ctrl+Shift+R) does not help; as it is imported via pom.xml.
3. Finding it thorugh quick-text searching (Ctrl+Shift+L) is no goer.
4. Finding it as a type (Ctrl+Shft+T) does not work.

**What worked:**

1. Writing in a project java file LdapClientServiceImpl allowed to import the bean and find it among maven-imported dependencies.

Is this the proper way? 
 I do not think so.
So how to find a bean in maven dependency in a proper way?

Comment: My response is not the best one. But if, eventually, can't find where your class can be, try to use JBosstattletale (http://tattletale.jboss.org/) : a tool that list all the classes and their location. Useful sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

I have two different strategies for you:

(1) using Eclipse with STS 3.9.x installed, you can open the type that defines the `@Service` annotation (if you are looking for something that is annotated with `@Service`). Then select the class name in the file, right-click, show references, and choose to search in the workspace. This produces a list of references to `@Service` annotation and will show you where it is being used even inside of libraries.

(2) go ahead and download the latest public beta of STS4 (https://spring.io/tools4), open a fresh workspace, and import your project. Make sure you are running your IDE with a JDK (not a JRE). And add the spring boot actuators to your dependencies (in case you are working with Spring Boot). Then start the project. The all-new STS4 tooling will highlight your Spring annotations in your source code with a green background and will tell you exactly which beans got wired in the live running application - and will allow you to navigate to that bean definition. That way you can directly see which beans got wired and where they come from (their type) and where they got defined as a bean (the resource, for example a `@Configuration` class).

Comment: About 1) I tried looking up the list of @Service beans in Spring Explorer and it did not show the service in there;
About 2) Interested in trying STS4. Cant really use the option you suggest as the project fails at autowiring stage.

Comment: please note that (1) is not about the Spring Explorer, that view is not involved there. Instead, I recommend to try the regular Java search features.